# How to mask first Nth position values present in string with *

Tags: postgresql

How to Mask first Nth position values present in string with "*"

`12345678` has to be replaced with `*` like =>  `******78` in postgresql

Comment: is it always 6 chars that need to be masked?

Comment: it can be N number size, not only 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the desired number of `*` with the substring:

```
select rpad('*',6,'*')||substr(input,6)
from (
  values ('12345678') 
) as t(input)
```

`rpad('*',6,'*')` generates six `*` characters and `substr(col,6)` takes everything after the sixth character from the input.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer. Please refer the below query. I wanted only last two digits of the number has to be viewed and remaining values will display as "*".

select lpad(right(colName,2), length(colName), '*') from my_table;